# OnCreate method is always called in when did share intent

Tags: android, flutter

i wrote a simple flutter app try to receive some external files by share intent

and i used a plugin called [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/documentation/receive_sharing_intent/latest/)
,however the `registerWith` method of this plugin would always be called when everytime i select some files to share with. that because the `onCreate` method would always invoke.

the activity lunchMode is `singleTop`, i thought the `onCreate` method should invoke once.

[image: the call stack is look like this]

could you give me any hints why this happen?

Thank You and Best Regards